# How to only replace NA with specific values based on a condition in another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, na, data-management

I need help to a solution. I have tried reading many earlier questions and answer but without a solution to my case. I want to keep the values in every variable but in the variable Udd I only want to change the NA values but keep the rest as it is.

Every time Udd is NA, I want it to change according to Edu.

*When Edu is from 1:7, I want Udd to be 1.
When Edu is from 8:11, I want Udd to be 2.
When Edu is from 12 and above, I want Udd to be 3.*

```
library(dplyr)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Edu <- c(4,7,9,13,15,18,11,10,12,8)
Udd <- c(1,NA,2,NA,3,3,2,NA,3,2)
d <- data.frame(ID, Edu, Udd)
d <- d %>%
  mutate(Udd = case_when(is.na(Udd) & Edu < 8 ~ 1,
                         is.na(Udd) & Edu[c(8,11)] ~ 2,
                         is.na(Udd) & Edu > 11 ~ 3))
```

It changes NA but returns rest as NA. I only want it to change the NA values, and keep the Udd values that are not NA as they were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the vector to have an %in% statement and added an else statement.

```
d %>%
  mutate(Udd = case_when(is.na(Udd) & Edu < 8 ~ 1,
                         is.na(Udd) & Edu %in% c(8:11) ~ 2,
                         is.na(Udd) & Edu > 11 ~ 3,
                         TRUE ~ Udd))
```

Comment: Hi, it returns this error: Error in 'mutate()': ! Problem while computing 'Udd = case_when(...)'. Caused by error in names(message) <- '"vtmp"' '': 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Comment: And I forgot to mention in my data Edu is numeric and Udd is a factor.

Comment: Can you cast Udd as a numeric (mutate(Udd = as.numeric(Udd)) ?

Comment: okay, and after this then maybe change it back to factor again? Because it is factor with labels for each category.